# Help needed to generically handle communication in a message queued environment-- multiple clients!

Tags: c

Assume there are 3 clients and a server.They communicate using a message queue , but the 3 clients send varying data (for ex 1st client may send a integer , 2nd may send a string etc). Is there any way for the server to generically handle this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Handle everything as a string, then, see if you can convert them if you absolutely have to (like you may have to convert string to int for math operations).

Now, to find out if you can convert a string to an integer, you can use [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) which returns a zero upon failure.

Comment: wat about user defined structure?? The thing is , i need to generically handle them and send via a socket to the other side where it must be able to retrieve the data!!

Comment: everything is preserved in a string, just send the string, and all communications are in strings on sockets because even if you send an integer, it gets put into a string.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest encoding the data.  [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is generally suitable for this.  What are you using for your message queue - if you haven't already take a look at [ZMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that the possible different data types are known (otherwise how can the server possibly handle them). Then you could use a union, e.g. something like:

```
union dataU{
    struct datatype1S datatype1;
    struct datatype2S datatype2;
    ...
}
struct messageS {
    int typeId;
    union dataU data;
}
```

Then use the typeId to determine what member of the union to look at.